# Load several configuration files with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm new to `RequireJs` library and so I have a question. In my application I have one localistation file (called `en.js`, `es.js`, etc) and exactly one settings file (`settings.js`). The first one is used to localize my application (change messages, titles etc.) and the second one is used to set some configuration on the app. So, what I want is to load both localisation file (say, `en.js`) and `settings.js` file, before the main application file is loaded. Here the file tree structure:

```
\static
    \js
        \locale
           en.js
        \config
           settings.js
        \app
           app.js
```

In tutorials I've seen only one entry point specified by `data-main`, like:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

But in my case it seems like there two main files (`en.js` and `settings.js`), that should be loaded first. So, what is the right way to implement this?

**EDIT**

For those who are new to modular JavaScript, I advise to read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/) article. I had spent many hours, trying to understand documentation and dozens tutorials, before I found this article. And I think, it is the best source of information for modular JavaScript newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to load two configurations before you start your application is to not use RequireJS to load this configuration but load it with `script` elements. You could have:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/settings.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/en.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["name of your main module"]);
</script>
```

The paths to `en.js` and `settings.js` are plain old JavaScript paths. `"name of your main module"` depends on what is in your RequireJS configuration, which you do not show in the question. I'd rather not assume. Given that `settings.js` is the *general* configuration for your application. I put it first so that `en.js` can benefit from it and contain only the minimum amount of code. So your `settings.js` would contain the general configuration options, which typically means at a minimum setting `baseUrl`, and most likely also `paths`:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "static/js",
    paths: {
        // whatever makes sense for your application
    }
});
```

And your `en.js` file would also call `requirejs.config` with whatever it needs. What you need there depends on what internationalization solution you use. Your `app.js` would be something like:

```
define([ ... deps ... ], function (... arguments ... ) {
    // start the application
});
```

What you need for `deps` depends on what your application actually uses. You do not need `en.js` there or `settings.js` because these have already been loaded.

This way you do not need to nest anything.

Comment: And if it is so, why then to use `require.js` and not just to load app.js with plain old `script`?

Comment: RequireJS is used to load everything else. Just not its own configuration. In the simplest cases, having RequireJS load its own configuration is okay but once you start multiplying configurations you are asking for trouble.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, but I did not plan to load its own configuration, I planned to load application configuration and localisation file. Both, `settings.js`, `en.js` and `app.js` do not contain any `requirejs` code.

Comment: What? Is it not the case that `settings.js` and `en.js` both contain calls to `requirejs.config`? And app.js is an AMD module that calls `define`? Otherwise, you should ask yourself the question "Why am *I* using RequireJS?"

Comment: It seems like not :( I think I'm too new to `RequireJS` and `AMD` concept. What I wanted to implement is just to load a bunch of configuration scripts strictly before `app.js`, that launches the application. I didn't know that I should obey some extra requirements.

Comment: Can you, please, share just the very basic teeny-weeny examples of how this template with two configuration files and one entry point (app.js) which depends on these two files may look like? I guess I need just a couple of lines of code to see how it all matches together.

Comment: I was asking this, because it seems rather hard to find a tutorial useful for those who are new to modular JavaScript. In fact I had spent several hours, before I found a really fundamental tutorial - http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/ . Official documentation, many github's tutorials suck.

Comment: I've edited the answer. This is about as precise as I can be. What you need to do specifically depends on the specifics of your application.

Answer (score 1):

If your module app.js needs en.js and settings.js to works here's a possibile structure for your main.js

**main.js**:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/static/js",
    paths: {
        en: "locale/en",
        settings: "config/settings",
        app: "app/app"
    }
});


requirejs(["en", "settings"], function(enRes, settingsRes) {

    //here you're sure that both modules are loaded

    // you can load app module
    requirejs(["app"], function(appRes) {
      //start your app
    });

});
```

Comment: I find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: @ Louis, What is wrong with that? I've not accepted it, yet, so you may share your own solution

Comment: @Jacobian It's not been accepted but it's been upvoted. This answer will result in intermittent failures. (Oh, and `mainConfigFile` is not a runtime option. It is an optimizer option.)

Comment: It was upvoted, because I do not like to discourage people, when they try to help.

Comment: I don't like overnesting too, but without knowing the logic of the code I wrote this. A better solution could be
`requirejs(["en", "settings","app"], function(enRes, settingsRes,appRes) { appRes.start()`.
@Louis what you think?

Comment: `requirejs(["en", "settings","app"]` <- does this guarantee, that app.js will be loaded after en.js and settings.js ?

Comment: The various dependencies in a single `require` (`requirejs`) call can be loaded in *any order* unless a dependency has been defined between them (which happens with `define` or a `shim`).

Comment: @Louis I've removed the optimizer option. (I forgot to remove when I've copied the code from one of my project)

Comment: @Pierfrancesco Okay, I'm not happy with the indeterminacy of order between `en` and `settings` but... hmm... if one is *really* *really* careful, they may get something that works. I would not do this in my own projects as I know what happens if I set up something which requires me to be really really careful weeks, months and years later: I forget that I had to walk on eggshells.